# AFNetworking Builds only in Debug. Release complains about missing ivars

Tags: ios, cocoa, afnetworking

Got a Mac OS X project that contains AFNetworking lib (latest source).
Build in Debug goes fine. However, a build in Release raise a lot of these errors:

```
Synthesized property 'baseURL' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar

Synthesized property 'stringEncoding' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar
```

that point to

```
@synthesize baseURL = _baseURL;
@synthesize stringEncoding = _stringEncoding;
```

etc.

Dived into the [code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h), and there's no `_baseURL` defined in the ivar section of the class (AFHTTPClient) or anywhere else. Just this synthesize and release at dealloc.

1. How come it builds (and works in debug) fine? Doesn't it really need that ivar?
2. What should I do in order to fix it?

Comment: Could it be that you are using a different compiler (LLVM/GCC) for each build? @property no longer has to be declared as an iVar.

Comment: Looks like it was "Build Active Architecture Only = No" that probably used a different compile that didn't add those ivars. After changing to `Yes` it worked. Thanks.